# Test immediately invoke function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm looking to create a test suite for a javascript file that contains an immediately invoked function. Eg.:

```
(function(context) {
    context.setVariable("a") = context.getVariable("a") + 1
})(context);
```

I am not able to change the file to be tested.

My current attempt is using `jest` and the following:

```
context = null

test('test1', () => {
    context = new context_mock();
    context.setVariable("a", "1");
    require("./My-Javascript");
    // Check result
    helper.check(context.getVariable("a"), 2);
});

test('test2', () => {
    context = new context_mock();
    context.setVariable("a", "2");
    require("./My-Javascript");
    // Check result
    helper.check(context.getVariable("a"), 3);
});
```

In this case, test 2 always fails. I assume it's because the javascript file can't be `require`d twice.

Edit: Yes `context` is a global variable that is operated on when the script is `require`d. I'm aware this is an ugly solution but I'm unable to change the original file.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: so .. `context` is a global variable? and what part in your jest code is dealing with the IIFE? it's not clear

Comment: You can use `require` twice, but it is cached. It's not clear from your question whether that's an issue or not. You should post enough code that someone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not make `test2` depend on the successful completion of `test1`?

Comment: I've updated the post. The caching is the issue (I assume) because the "global" `context` variable isn't operated on in the second test (which subsequently fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest` has an extra level of caching the modules which is preventing the `require` from running multiple times.

Adding the following to clear the modules cache prior to calls allows the script to run multiple times:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
});
```